# Looking up Similar Text Strings in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a vlookup from one sheet into another. But the data is not that perfect.  I need to be able to find extact matches , and if not found try look for very close matches . I have failed to find a way around this. I am open to vba code suggestions as well.

```
=IF(B2="AD Non Chargeable","Internal",VLOOKUP(B2&"*",Sheet2!A:B,2,0))
```

The wildcard works to a certain extent but i am having issues where some string are one word instead of 2 words etc.

Some text has S.à .r.l. at the of end name so its not being picked up as well. NA

Comment: Wildcard matches using *?

Comment: Or google fuzzy lookups. There is a microsoft fuzzy lookup add-in. No idea if any good.

Comment: Might imply that there is white space or hidden special characters - have you used len to check lengths of expected matches?

Comment: If you know some of the edge cases can you implement some logic that checks for these and if present,for example, does a substitute to create two words etc. A sort of normalization if you will.

Comment: I'm going to echo fuzzy matching - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Comment: Have you tried the MATCH() function? can work well if you combine with INDEX()..